# .tar.gz or .rpm for adobe flash download for google chrome?

Tags: upgrade

I have a linux 64-bit operating system. I want to download adobe flash. It is asking me which version to download, .tar.gz or .rpm. How do I find out which version I need?

Comment: Flash comes already bundled in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome has Flash built into it. You can download it [here](https://www.google.de/chrome/browser/desktop/).

To use it with Firefox, just run `sudo apt install flashplugin-installer`.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome automatically updates when new versions of Flash so you shouldn't need to do a manual install.

[see this article from adobe for more info](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html)